# Find $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \frac{x\sin x}{1+x^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x\sin x}{1+x^2}$$

Using L'hopital I get:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x\cos x + \sin x}{2x}=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\cos x}{2}$$

However, how is it possible to evaluate this limit?

Comment: The title and the question body do not match: you want the limit for $x\to 0$ or $x\to +\infty$? Moreover, before applying l'Hopital theorem, check if its hypothesis are fulfilled. And maybe try to think to a simpler approach.

Comment: Another example of the awful influence L'Hopital can have. If indeed the limit is when $x\to\infty$ (and not $x\to0$ as in the title) then *think!* You know next to nothing about the sine except that is is bounded by $1$ hence your function is bounded by $|x|/(1+x^2)\leqslant1/|x|$. And $x\to\infty$ hence...

Comment: The numerator doesn't satisfy l'Hôpital's hypothesis. Why?

Comment: @hjhjhj57 To top limit does not exist, hence the limit is not an indeterminant form. i.e. $\frac{\text{DNE}}{\infty}$

Answer (score 13):

You have $$\left\vert \frac{x \sin x}{1+x^2}\right\vert \le \frac{\vert x \vert}{1+x^2}$$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 6):

Try evaluating
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x}{1+x^2}\sin(x)$$
keeping in mind that $\sin$ is a bounded function..

Answer (score 4):

L'Hopital's Rule doesn't apply here, since $\lim_{x\to\infty}x\sin x$ is *undefined*, not either $\infty$ or $-\infty$. Indeed, it oscillates with larger and larger "waves" as $x \to \infty$, and so in some sense tends to both $\infty$ and $-\infty$ at the same time. So the limitand is not an indeterminate form as $x \to \infty$.

Instead, here's a hint: What are the values of the limits $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\pm x}{x^2+1}$? Can you relate this to your original limit?

Answer (score 1):

You can't apply L'Hospital rule here: it supposes numerator and denominator *both* tend to $0$ or to $\infty$.

Unfortunately, the numerator has no limit as $x\to\infty$.

This is a fine example that L'Hospital's rule is dangerous. Although for some, it seems to be the alpha and omega of limits computation, when it works, it is logically equivalent to using Taylor's formula at order $1$, and very often, asymptotic calculus with equivalent function is much swifter:

$$x\sin x =O(x), \enspace 1+x^2\sim_\infty x^2,\enspace\text{hence}\quad \frac{x\sin x}{1+x^2}=\frac1{x^2}O(x)=O\Bigl(\frac1x\Bigr)\to 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Some answers are saying L'Hopital is not applicable here because the numerator does not $\to \pm \infty.$ Actually L'Hopital is valid if we assume only the denominator $\to \pm \infty:$ If $f,g$ are differentiable on $(a,\infty), \lim_{x\to \infty} g(x) = \pm \infty,$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = L,$ then $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = L.$

For some reason this "better" L'Hopital is not as well known as the usual L'Hopital. It should be, because the proof is about as easy as the usual one, and the result resembles its cousin, the Stolz-Cesaro theorem for convergence of a sequence. (Recall that in SC, only the denominator sequence is assumed to $\to \pm \infty.$)

Comment: What you say is very true. L'Hospital Rule is applicable here, *but it is not helpful here* as the limit of $f'(x)/g'(x)$ does not exist in this question.

Comment: Actually it isn't applicable - for the reason you say. However, saying it's not applicable simply because $f(x)\not \to \pm \infty$ is what I was commenting on. (Frankly, the rule is not helpful most of the time in my opinion, as there are usually better ways of seeing the limit, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: Fully agree with "the rule is not helpful most of the time"...

Answer (score 0):

Don't think L'Hospital applies here - the top limit does not exist. Hence, you are forced resort to a more fundamental approach like pointed out in other answers

Comment: I think the top is undefined (and bottom aswell giving an indeterminant form), because as $x$ inceases without bound, $-1 \leq \sin x \leq 1$ and so $x \sin x \rightarrow \pm \infty$. Hence you can use L'Hopital's. Oh, are you saying that the top limit DNE because it is not distinctly $-\infty$ or $\infty$? Either way, it gives an indeterminant form.

Comment: @JesterTran it is neither $+\infty$ or $-\infty$, it does not exist...

Comment: I now understand that it does not exist but either way, it gives an indeterminant form. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @JesterTran LHospital cannot be used when limits don't exist. You need too make s bonding argument like shown in other answers

Comment: So the limit is neither $\frac{-\infty}{\infty}$ nor $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, hence not an indeterminant form as $x \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: @JesterTran yes. Exactly

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Note that we have an application of the squeeze theorem here. We do not have L'Hopital's rule for the reasons mentioned above. However, we do have
$$
-\frac{x}{x^2+1}\leq \frac{x\sin(x)}{x^2+1}\leq\frac{x}{x^2+1}.
$$
using the bound $-1\leq\sin(x)\leq 1$. Since the limit of the upper and lower bounds go to $0$ as $x\to\infty$, the Squeeze theorem implies that 
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x\sin(x)}{x^2+1}=0.~_{\square}
$$